# Jersey Grizzly Containers w/ @WebListener ServletContextListeners

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-2.0, grizzly, servletcontextlistener

I've got my JAX-RS web services running with grizzly-server, but I cannot configure my @WebListener to work. I am building a framework so I cannot switch to Grizzly listeners.

I've got the latest libraries.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
    <artifactId>grizzly-http-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.30</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Here is some code:

```
@ApplicationPath("/SampleAdmin")
public class SampleAdminApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public SampleAdminApplication() {
        packages("com.companyname.sample.sampleadmin.server.services");
    }
}

    @WebListener
    public class SampleAdminListener implements ServletContextListener {
        private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SampleAdminListener.class);

        @Override
        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
            log.info("SampleAdminListener Initializing context.");
        }

        @Override
        public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
            log.info("SampleAdminListener Destroying context.");
        }
    }
    /**
     * Starts Grizzly HTTP server exposing JAX-RS resources defined in this application.
     * @return Grizzly HTTP server.
     */
    public static HttpServer startServer() {
        // create a resource config that scans for JAX-RS resources and providers
        // in com.example.rest package
        final ResourceConfig rc = new SampleAdminApplication();

        // create and start a new instance of grizzly http server
        // exposing the Jersey application at BASE_URI
        HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);

        WebappContext context = new WebappContext("WebappContext", "/" + webapp);
        context.addListener("com.vilabs.sample.sampleadmin.server.servlet.SampleAdminListener");
        context.addFilter("SampleAdminFilter", SampleAdminFilter.class);
        context.addFilter("SampleAdminCsrfFilter", SampleAdminCsrfFilter.class);
//        ServletRegistration registration = context.addServlet("ServletContainer", new ServletContainer(rc));
        ServletRegistration registration = context.addServlet("ServletContainer", new ServletContainer(rc));
        registration.addMapping("/*");

        context.deploy(httpServer);
        return httpServer;
    }
```

The call to context.deploy(httpServer) throws IllegalStateException.

```
Jun 06, 2017 7:14:14 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext deploy
SEVERE: [WebappContext] Exception deploying application.  See stack trace for details.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context.
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext.initServlets(WebappContext.java:1833)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext.deploy(WebappContext.java:318)
    at com.vilabs.sample.sampleadmin.server.SampleServer.startServer(SampleServer.java:60)
    at com.vilabs.sample.sampleadmin.server.SampleServer.main(SampleServer.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:221)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.register(ResourceConfig.java:453)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext.initServlets(WebappContext.java:1831)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> IllegalStateException: The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context

It's because `createHttpServer(uri, resourceConfig)` automatically starts the server unless the boolean flag is passed to the overloaded method, telling it *not* to auto-start.

Another thing is that you are are trying to create two applications. Once when you call `createHttpServer` passing the `ResourceConfig`, and another time when you create the `ServletContainer` with the same `ResourceConfig`.

What you should do is just the overloaded `createHttpServer(uri)`. This won't create an application, and won't start the server. And you create the Jersey application when you create the `ServletContainer` with the `ResourceConfig`, and pass it to the `WebAppContext`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, The Filters and Listeners are working

```
/**
 * Starts Grizzly HTTP server exposing JAX-RS resources defined in this application.
 * @return Grizzly HTTP server.
 */
public static HttpServer startServer() {
    // create a resource config that scans for JAX-RS resources and providers
    // in com.example.rest package
    final ResourceConfig rc = new SampleAdminApplication();

// create and start a new instance of grizzly http server
// exposing the Jersey application at BASE_URI
HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI));

WebappContext context = new WebappContext("WebappContext", "/" + webapp);
context.addListener("com.vilabs.sample.sampleadmin.server.servlet.SampleAdminListener");
context.addFilter("SampleAdminFilter", SampleAdminFilter.class);
context.addFilter("SampleAdminCsrfFilter", SampleAdminCsrfFilter.class);
ServletRegistration registration = context.addServlet("ServletContainer", new ServletContainer(rc));
registration.addMapping("/*");

context.deploy(httpServer);
return httpServer;
}
```